# Fill several sections below a curve of data in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, fill, curves

I have a set of points "data" defining a curve that I want to plot with bezier smooth.
So I want to fill the area below that curve between some pairs of x values.
If I only had one pair of x values it's not that difficult because I define a new set of data and plot it with filledcu. Example:

[image: example of what I want to do]

The problem is that I want to do that several times in the same plot.

Edit: Minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal wxt enhanced font 'Verdana,12'

set style fill transparent solid 0.35 noborder
plot 'data' using 1:2 smooth sbezier with lines ls 1
pause -1
```

Where the structure of 'data' is:

```
x_point y_point
```

And I realized that my problem is that in fact I can't fill not even one curve, it seems to be filled because the slope is almost constant there.

Comment: Can you post the script (or a minimal version thereof) that you used to make that example? It may be a simple modification to get what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fill parts below a curve, you must use the `filledcurves` style. With the option `x1` you fill the part between the curve and the x-axis.

In order to fill only parts of the curve, you must filter your data, i.e. give the x-values a value of `1/0` (invalid data point) if they are outside of the desired range, and the correct value from the data file otherwise. At the end you plot the curve itself:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.35 noborder
filter(x,min,max) = (x > min && x < max) ? x : 1/0
plot 'data' using (filter($1, -1, -0.5)):2 with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using (filter($1, 0.2, 0.8)):2 with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using 1:2 with lines lw 3 lt 1 title 'curve'
```

This fills the range `[-1:0.5]` and `[0.2:0.8]`.

To give a working example, I use the special filename `+`:

```
set samples 100
set xrange [-2:2]
f(x) = -x**2 + 4

set linetype 1 lc rgb '#A3001E'

set style fill transparent solid 0.35 noborder
filter(x,min,max) = (x > min && x < max) ? x : 1/0
plot '+' using (filter($1, -1, -0.5)):(f($1)) with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using (filter($1, 0.2, 0.8)):(f($1)) with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using 1:(f($1)) with lines lw 3 lt 1 title 'curve'
```

With the result (with 4.6.4):

[image]

If you must use some kind of smoothing, the filter may affect the data curve differently, depending on the filtered part. You can first write the smoothed data to a temporary file and then use this for 'normal' plotting:

```
set table 'data-smoothed'
plot 'data' using 1:2 smooth bezier
unset table

set style fill transparent solid 0.35 noborder
filter(x,min,max) = (x > min && x < max) ? x : 1/0
plot 'data-smoothed' using (filter($1, -1, -0.5)):2 with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using (filter($1, 0.2, 0.8)):2 with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     ''  using 1:2 with lines lw 3 lt 1 title 'curve'
```

Comment: Great, that works, but one more thing, I want to plot my data with smooth sbezier, but then the filled section doesn't match the curved
For example replacing in the last part of plot:

`''  using 1:2 smooth sbezier with lines lw 3 lt 1 title 'curve'`

[Image](http://i.imgur.com/j9lkjXO.png)

Comment: I can also see this, but I don't know why this happens. If you use `smooth csplines` (for every line in the `plot` command), then it works fine for me.

Comment: I can't use `smooth csplines` in the second plot command because it throws an error `Can't calculate splines, need at least 3 points
` . Anyway [csplines doesn't approximate the curve the way I want to](http://i.imgur.com/VLOpzLr.png).

Comment: Please see my edited answer. The best way I know is to write the smoothed data to a temporal file and then use this with the suggested filtering and plotting.