# Gnuplot Filledcurves

Tags: gnuplot, fill

I am trying to use gnuplot to fill between a curve and the x axis for a certain xrange. For example I would like to fill between the line f(x)=x when x<5.

Example code:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set samples 100
plot x with filledcurves above x1=5
```

When this is plotted in Gnuplot 5.0 it does not show any fill.

I can try the reverse of:

`plot x with filledcurves below x1=5`

This gets closer because it fills below the line f(x)=x when x<5, however, it also shades the area above when x>5. There is also no way to limit it to above the x axis as well.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no "direct" way to do it. Christoph gives a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027903/fill-several-sections-below-a-curve-of-data-in-gnuplot).

Based on his code I came up with the following:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]

filter_lt(x,xmax) = ((x < xmax) ? x : 1/0)
f(x) = x
xmax = 5

plot '+' using (filter_lt($1,xmax)):(f($1)) with filledcurves x1 lt 1 notitle,\
     '' using 1:(f($1)) with lines lw 2 lt 1 title 'f(x)=x'
```